# How to prove that this "priority" strategy (in ANTLR4) solves the "dangling-else" ambiguity?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, compilers, parsers, ambiguity

As shown in this [post @ stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70108537/1833118), ANTLR4 *seems* able to resolve the ["dangling-else" ambiguity @ wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else) in the following "if-then-else" grammar by prioritizing the "`'if' expr 'then' stat`" alternative to "`'if' expr 'then' stat 'else' stat`". But I have some difficulty

```
stat : 'if' expr 'then' stat
     | 'if' expr 'then' stat 'else' stat
     | expr
     ;
```

Is this the correct way to resolve this ambiguity using ANTLR4? If so, how to prove that this "priority" works for all valid if/then/else statements?

Comment: Actually, you should make the second production the priority, if it is possible (that is, if  `else` is the next token).

Comment: That Wikipedia article becomes worse every time I look at it. I think there is a better version buried in the revision history before it was butchered. But there are discussions here on SO about how to use precedence declarations in parser generators which have them (yacc and its derivatives, for example) and even the WP page still mentions that you can resolve the ambiguity correctly by preferring shift to reduce.

Comment: Since I see you have the Dragon book, take a look at the discussion of dangling else in &section;4.8.2. The authors only describe the success of the default resolution strategy, although some people prefer to use an explicit precedence declaration to avoid the conflict warning, rather than using `%expect`.

Comment: @rici "you should make the second production the priority": however, ANTLR4 parses `"if a then if b then c else d"` as `"if a then (if b then c) else d"` if I make the second production the priority. I am quite confused about this. It is probably related to the mechanism of ANTLR4. But what is it? (I now understand why we should perfer shift to reduce in LR. Thanks.)

Comment: antlr is a top-down parser. A bottom-up algorithm wouldn't have to decide about the outer `if` until the inner `if` is done, so the first ambiguity with a bottom-up parser concerns the inner `if`. But since Antlr must decide right away, it is important that it chooses the shorter option for the outer `if`. If it turns out that both `if` statements have `else` clauses, then the decision about the outer `if` will be proven wrong, which for Antlr is OK because it knows how to backtrack. Bottom line: "priority" in Antlr is not the same concept as "precedence" in yacc.

Comment: At least, that's my theory. I'm far from an Antlr expert but it seems like a plausible explanation. So I guess my first comment was wrong, in Antlr terms. It was right for yacc/bison.

Comment: @rici I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ANTLR4 matches grammar alternatives against the input in the order you specify them.  That production says (assuming "else" cannot be parsed as an *expr*) to bind the `else` to the most recent `if` - parsing this:

```
if a=b then if c=d then something else some_other_thing
```

as

```
if a=b then {
   if c=d then {
      something
   } else {
      some_other_thing
   }
}
```

If you want the opposite behavior - binding the `else` to the earliest possible `if` - then reverse the order of the first two alternatives.

Comment: Apparently that's not true, and it surprised me, too. See [OP's comment responding to the same suggestion](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/146319/how-to-prove-that-this-priority-strategy-in-antlr4-solves-the-dangling-else#comment308874_146319) (and the rest of the comment thread).

Comment: @rici From "_The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference_", p. 15, written by ANTLR's designer: "If the parser detects an ambiguous phrase, it has to pick one of the viable alternatives. ANTLR resolves the ambiguity by choosing the first alternative involved in the decision."

Comment: yes. So what is the first alternative? Since Antlr is top-down, the first decision point is the outer `if`. And if you work top-down, which is effectively outside-in, you need to first consider the alternative without an `else`, and only use the `else` if no inner production is able to.

Comment: Anyway, theory is theory, but Antlr is a product and it can be tried.

Comment: ANTLR (or, at least, Parr's book), is clear: an "alternative" is quite literally that - an alternative in a grammar production.  Thus, the `stat` non-terminal has 3 alternatives: `if/then`, `if\then\else`, and `expr`.  But yeah, it's testable.

Comment: perhaps I read your answer incorrectly. Now that I read it again, I'm not sure what you mean by "that production". If you mean, "the grammar as presented in OP", then it's correct; the presented grammar works. OP wanted to know why (and I did, too). Because if you put the same productions into a bottom-up generator like bison, which also claims to use the first alternative in the case of conflict, you'll get the opposite result. So just saying "it uses the first alternative" doesn't seem to tell the whole story. But if I misinterpreted your answer, I apologise.